# How to create a restricted SSH account for a GIT repository?

Tags: linux, git

How is the best way I can create a jailed user on a Linux machine to be used solely for a git repository?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`git-shell`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) is a restricted shell that you can use for this purpose.

If you make set a user's login shell to `git-shell` then he can only run a limited set of server-side git helper functions which enable remote git over ssh usage but don't permit a normal log in.

Comment: Here is a good documentation on how to achieve that http://progit.org/book/ch4-4.html

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.  For future readers, I ended up on this site for easy steps on setting this up: http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2012/04/git-over-ssh-restrict-user-to-git.html

Answer (score 1):

Also look in to gitosis. In particular, it sets some parameters in .ssh/authorized_keys which prevent port forwarding, etc:

```
command="gitosis-serve user@host",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA....
```

Even if you do not use gitosis, you may want to include the restrictive options.

Comment: Gitosis is no longer maintained and supported by the author; most people usually recommend gitolite instead which has much better documentation and more features: http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Comment: @Seth - ah, I had not noticed that gitosis was deprecated (though last update in 2009, I guess I should have). Thanks for the note!